# Unable to refresh page when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, button, load, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to build some SvelteKit page with a button to get an ID generated randomly from the server side. As load system works for a page loading, I tried :

EDIT: I have corrected my code according to HB's comment.

```
// src/routes/test/+page.js
const generateID = () => {
    let key = '00:12:34:56:63'
    
    /* randomize an array of length N with with 64-digits */
    /* and join it with ':' to build a string */
    
    return key
}

// EDIT: track affeced/attributed keys    
const lookups = new Map ()

// EDIT: added 'depends' parameter
export const load = async ({ params, depends }) => {
    let uid
    
    do {
        uid = generateID ()
    } while (lookups.has (uid))
    
    lookups.set (uid, 1)
    
    // EDIT: ddepends usage
    depends ('app:randomkey')

    return {
        props: {
            uid
        }
    }
}
```

and the client side looks like:

```
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    // -- import { goto } from '$app/navigation'
    import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation'
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
     
    export let data
    
    const handler = () => {
       // EDIT: do not use 'goto' anymore
       // goto ($page.url.pathname)
       // EDIT: use 'depends key' instead
       invalidate ('app:randomkey')
    }
</script>
<p> Click button to refresh UID from server </p>
<p>     
    <button on:click={ handler }> refresh UID </button>
    { data.props.key } 
</p>
```

At page reload 'F5 on keyboard) ut refresh the UID "key" value, but NOT when cluicking the button

So what's wring ? and I could fix it, while persisiting application layout and internal state  ?

EDIT: et voilà !

Enjoy coding !

Answer (score 2):

The URL is the same, hence nothing changes.
You should use [`invalidate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#invalidation-manual-invalidation) instead.

Comment: I missed this point in the docs... page is reloaded OK, while app stores will keeping states, stores and layout,  so you could count the number of clicks on the button Refresh and display them at bottom of the page ! ... awesome. Thanks to HB ;-)

Comment: Glad it helps. If that sufficiently answered your question, you accept the answer using the checkmark outline to its side. (You seem to have never accepted any answers, so I would recommend checking your earlier questions and accepting valid answers there as well.)